# null value in column "ProjectName_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

need help on null value in column "ProjectName_id" violates not-null constraint, im new to django
i want my ProjectName_id (Foreignkey) is the same id that user choose in my
 majordetails = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.get(id=sid) please help me...

my model views

```
class ProjectNameInviToBid(models.Model):
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name', null=True)
    DateCreated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

```
class InviToBid(models.Model):
    today = date.today()
    ProjectName = models.ForeignKey('ProjectNameInviToBid', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    NameOfFile = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name of File')
```

my views.py

```
def project_name_details(request, sid):

    majordetails = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.get(id=sid)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            majordetails = InviToBid.ProjectName
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File has been Uploaded')
    else:
        form = invitoBidForm()

    args = {
        'majordetails': majordetails,
        'form': form

    }
    return render(request,'content/invitoBid/bacadmininvitoBid.html', args)
```

```
class ProjectNameInviToBidForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = ProjectNameInviToBid
        fields = ('ProjectName',)


class invitoBidForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = InviToBid
        fields = ('NameOfFile', 'Contract_No', 'Bid_Opening',
                  'Pre_Bid_Conference', 'Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee',
                  'Delivery_Period',
                  'Pdf_fileinvi')
```

Comment: I cannot see the `majordetails` in the `InviToBid` model, maybe you want to add the `ProjectName=majordetails` after `form.is_valid` is that what you want to do?

Comment: i want the ProjectNameInviToBid.id is eqaul to ProjectName sir.

Comment: ok, got it, are the two forms both model forms? can you post them as well in the question?

Comment: i add it sir @SammyJ

Comment: Add `ProjectName` in fields to `invitoBidForm` and check this form in your HTML, does a dropdown appear for this field?

Comment: yes sir. if i add the ProjectName the dropdown will appear, but i want to the ProjectName and the majordetails will have the same value how can i do that sir? @SammyJ

Comment: Just pass the instance to the form, `form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=majordetails)`

Comment: how do i target to ProjectName field sir my instance? it still asking for value the ProjectName field @SammyJ

Comment: ok, just post your entire error traceback in the question, we must look at it

Comment: in my template, ProjectName field(this field is required)